# jquery nth child that is currently visible

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I can style every 4th 'item' div like so

```
  jQuery(".item:nth-child(4n)").addClass("fourth-item");
```

and that works fine, but then I hide some items, show some others and want to re-do this styling, but only styling every 4th item that is visible. So I have a function that will remove this styling and reapply it, but I need to specify in the reapplying of the style that it is only every 4th visible item, not every 4th item. I know the ":visible" selector but can't seen to chain it with the nth-child selector properly, any ideas?

I've tried various things like this to no avail...

```
jQuery(".item").removeClass("fourth-item");
jQuery(".item:visible:nth-child(4n)").addClass("fourth-item");
```

Comment: [How to get nth-child selector to skip hidden divs using CSS only](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32380418/3597276)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`:nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) scans the children of the parent no matter what their styling is. The counting in [`:nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) is relative to the parent element, not the previous selector. This is explained in the jQuery docs for `:nth-child`:

> With `:nth-child(n)`, all children are counted, regardless of what they are, and the specified element is selected only if it matches the selector attached to the pseudo-class.

Using a more simple method with `each` does exactly what you want:

```
$('#test li:visible').each(function (i) {
    if (i % 4 == 0) $(this).addClass('fourth-item');
});
```

Comment: Well, it depends! Note that `nth-child` is `1` based, while here `i` is `0` based.

Comment: Perfect answer. I did have to use @mbehan's suggestion of i + 1 for it to work as expected on every 4th element.