# Create a div every each 3 divs that are visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to display a "receptacle" after each 3 divs that are visible. Because following the filter each div is hidden or not.

I want the receptacle just after each 3 divs... but if the articles ends by one or two on the line just put a receptacle after them.

Ex:
html

```
<div class="container">
    <article style="display:block"></article>
    <article style="display:block"></article>
    <article style="display:none"></article>
    <article style="display:block"></article>
    <article style="display:none"></article>
    <article style="display:block"></article>
    <article style="display:block"></article>
    <article style="display:none"></article>
    <article style="display:block"></article>
    <article style="display:block"></article>
</div>
```

js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('.container > article:visible:nth-child(3n)').after('<div class="receptacle"></div>');

    $('article').each(function () {
        $(this).on('click', function () {
            $(this).nextAll('receptacle').text('toto');
        });
    });

});
```

css

```
article {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    height:40px;
    background:DeepSkyBlue;
    margin:5px;
}
```

the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/XLK6z/

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a fiddle that better shows what's happening. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/XLK6z/2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175694/jquery-nth-child-that-is-currently-visible should help with your problem. It looks like it does the nth-child selector is applied first and then the visible. So the `div` is only getting inserted after visible nth childs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like nth-child is "applied" to `.container > article` and not to `.container > article:visible`. Then you may filter "manually":

```
var $visible = $('.container > article:visible');
$visible.each(function(idx) {
    if (idx % 3 === 2 || idx === $visible.length - 1) {
         $(this).after('<div class="receptacle"></div>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the original ordering problem: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/XLK6z/3/

Comment: Shouldn't `idx % 3` equal `0` not `2`?

Comment: No. This code works as expected: places `div.receptacle` after each 3rd visible div. Why it is so? I'll leave it to you ;-)

Comment: This is perfect Kirilloid. Thanks everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your CSS. Everything works fine, but you're floating the articles around.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/XLK6z/6

```
article {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Oh, I did add a dot to your receptacle selector in the click function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that works:  http://jsfiddle.net/XLK6z/8/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".container article").each(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":visible")){
            if ($(this).prevAll("article:visible").length%3 === 2  || $(this).is(":last-child")) {
                $(this).after('<div class="receptacle"></div>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```