# Add a specific class to every 4th li that is displayed/visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Newbie in Javascript and in English, please forgive my writing.

I've searched and came across many posts explaining how I should add a class but they are not the same as what I need to do.

I would like to add a specific class to every 4th `li` that is displayed (or is visible), by which I mean, I have some `li` that are not displayed and they should be excluded from the counter:

```
<section>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
      window.onload=function(){
        $('.liste li:nth-child(4)').addClass('lastli');
      };
    //-->
  </script>

  <ul class="liste">
    <li>1 Lorem</li>
    <li>2 ipsum</li>
    <li>3 dolor</li>
    <li style="display:none;">4 sin amet</li>
    <li>5 consectetur</li> <!-- add a lastli class here -->
    <li>6 aliquam</li>
    <li style="display:none;">7 lobortis</li>
    <li>8 Fusce</li>
    <li>9 fringilla</li>
    <li>10 rutrum</li> <!-- add a lastli class here -->
    <li>11 dapibus</li>
    <li style="display:none;">12 nunc</li>
    <li>13 nunc</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: So what's not working for you? Where's your css for the class `lastli`?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of SO 2175694 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175694/jquery-nth-child-that-is-currently-visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the other answers not <strike>is</strike> *was* considering that you want *every* forth `<li>` to have the class `lastli`, and `also` want to ignore `<li>`'s with `display:none;`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    count=0;
    $('li:visible').each(function(i, e) {
        count=count+1;      
        if (count==4) {
            $(e).addClass('lastli');
            count=0;
        }
    });
});
```

does the job right. Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/bAs3d/

Answer (score 4):

You can do it the below way:

```
var lstItems = $('.liste li').filter(function () {
    return $(this).is(':visible');
});

$(lstItems).each(function (i) {
    if ((i % 4) === 3) $(this).addClass('lastli');
});
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the OP question of needing to select every 4th *visible* `<li>`. Some of them are not displayed and he doesn't want those included in the "every 4th item" count.

Comment: No he's not. Look at the code he posted and where he's specified the class to be added.

Comment: @Scottie: I think I got what you mean now. Maybe if OP added two hidden li somewhere in between it would have been clearer.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely open to interpretation. I'm going by his statement of `I would like to add a specific class to every 4th li displayed` to mean that he wants every 4th visible li to have the class added to it, essentially skipping over everything that's hidden. I've rescinded the downvote because hey, we're all friends here. :D  //edit: drat, SO isn't letting me change my vote unless your question is edited. D:

Answer (score 2):

### Update

```
$('.liste li:visible').each(function (i) {
    if (i % 4 == 3) {
        $(this).addClass('lastli');
    }
});
```

---

I really thought this next method would have worked, but apparently not!

```
$('.liste li:visible:nth-child(4n)').addClass('lastli');
```

Comment: I just tested this and it only returns `<li>8 Fusce</li>` which doesn't seem correct to my understanding of the OP.

Comment: @Scottie exactly. I posted it, went off to test it, but by then had 2 upvotes, so thought I must have done something wrong!

Comment: using the :visible selector was half-way.. see SO2175691 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175694/jquery-nth-child-that-is-currently-visible

Comment: @AardVark71 thanks for the explanation. I came up with the workaround but couldn't explain *why* what seemed so logical wasn't working!

Comment: It doesnt work, highlight only "8 Fusce" and totally ignores "4 sin amet"

Answer (score 2):

just write a css-rule similar to this:

```
.liste > li:nth-child(4)
{
    /*yourstyle*/
}
```

you will get what you want!