# CSS - Add class to the 3n+4 'visible' list item

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Im trying to apply a class to every 3 list items beginning with the 4th (3n+4).
This works fine using CSS when all list items are visible.

Unfortunately, when some list items are hidden (display: none), the nth-child selector applies to those hidden list items as well.

I need the CSS to apply to only visible list items, so I did some research and tried using jQuery and the visible selector to achieve the desired result. This didn't work either.

Please see my current code below for an example.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xuqwf

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li style="display: none;">2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li style="display: none;">6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px orange solid;
  margin: 5px;
}

ul li:nth-child(3n+4) {
  background: green;
}

.clear {
  background: red;
}
```

**jQuery (Tried and failed)**

```
$('ul li:visible:nth-child(3n+4)').addClass('clear');
```

Comment: You jQuery [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/VQ337/1/) - What do you mean it fails?

Comment: instead of using inline styling, you should use a class and then could use CSS only

Comment: @oGeez - I don't think it does... http://jsfiddle.net/VQ337/3/

Comment: Just checked following my comment, sorry my bad, doesn't work

Comment: @Adam What's wrong with that? Every 3, starting from 4, that isn't hidden. So the div containing 6 is highlighted?

Comment: @Adam I can see your point now, apologies.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2175694/1499781

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop:

```
var i = 0;
$('ul li:visible').each(function(index,el) {
 if((index+1)%(3*i+4) == 0) {
   $(this).addClass('clear');
   i++;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JQuery is working fine. Put the hidden list items into a "sub list" within the main list container. Then apply the JQuery strictly to the "main list"

Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/defmetalhead/VQ337/9/

```
<ul class="mainList">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3
    <ul>
      <li style="display: none;">3-1</li>
      <li style="display: none;">3-2</li>
      <li style="display: none;">3-3</li>
      <li style="display: none;">3-4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

New Jquery line

```
$('.mainList').children('li:nth-child(3n+4)').addClass('clear');
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as a static list but my list is created programmatically, I feel it would be a nightmare to try and achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting every 3rd child's properties with CSS selection, add a class to them using jQuery, then replace the class when you want to change them to green. You can not override the CSS selector `ul li:nth-child(3n+4)`.

**CSS:**

```
ul li {
background: yellow;
border: 1px orange solid;
margin: 5px;
}

.green {
 background: green;
}

.hide {
 display: none;
}

.clear {
background: red;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('ul li:visible:nth-child(3n+4)').addClass('green');
$('ul li:visible:nth-child(3n+4)').removeClass('green').addClass('clear');
```