# Jquery selecting every 12th visible element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

As the title says, how do I select every 12th element which is visible?
I've tried searching for it in these ways:

```
$("#content_div > div > img:nth-child(12n):visible").after("<div></div>");
$("#content_div > div > img:visible:nth-child(12n)").after("<div></div>");
```

None of the ways worked

Comment: Do you want every 12th element or every 8th? Your question says 8th but the title and code indicate 12th. And, can you add a sample of the markup you're trying to use this on?

Comment: I've changed the title, I'm pretty sleepy, my bad, sorry

Comment: I would recommend trying the modulus approach noted in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175694/jquery-nth-child-that-is-currently-visible) if you are having trouble. That answer also answers your question to your approach.

Comment: We will need your HTML to answer that...

Comment: The correct answer is deleted, though it was just a link to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175694/jquery-nth-child-that-is-currently-visible

Thanks to that mysterious comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#content_div > div > img:visible:nth-of-type(12n)").after("<div></div>")
```

See [:nth-of-type() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/)

```js
$.each(new Array(36), function() {
  $("#content_div > div").append(
    $("<img>")
  )
});

$("#content_div > div > img:visible:nth-of-type(12n)").after("<div>visible</div>")
```

```css
img {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:navy;
  padding:1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content_div">
 <div></div>
</div>
```